# Align image to be centred with one line of text, but then top aligned when there's more lines

Tags: html, css

When there's only one line of text, then I want the icon to be aligned in the centre, which is what I have achieved, however what I need to achieve now is when there's more than one line (resizing the screen), the icon should be aligned at the top. Any ideas how I can achieve this without media queries, as the content inside the p tag will be different each time.

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}

.rounded-container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 14px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 14px;
  padding-left: 60px;
  background: yellow;
}

.rounded-container[data-icon-name="account"]::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 14px;
  top: 0;
  content: "";
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://svgshare.com/i/qKT.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="rounded-container" data-icon-name="account">
  <p>Please login into your account to see your paperless statements</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the icon to have 100% of container height, meaning that it can never reach top when there are more lines (because you centered your icon with background tags), simply change its height to, for example, `height: 40px;` so you will have:

```
.rounded-container[data-icon-name="account"]::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 14px;
  top: 0;
  content: "";
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-image: url('https://svgshare.com/i/qKT.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Note that now it is at the very top, you might need to add so pixels to the `top` property to align it with the text. `top: 10px` looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add an event listener which listens for `window resize` and compare the height of each paragraph against a pre-defined constant value when the `paragraph` text does not break into two lines.

If you find such paragraph, you simply toggle a class for which you have pre-defined styles in your `CSS`, and walla, its done. Here is MY solution. This should work out of the box, the only thing you might need to change is the `reference`, which may vary but that is solvable (you can see how the reference changes based on the window width).

JavaScript:

```
const reference = 22 // How many pixels the paragraph occupies when not braking into a new line. Change this in your case according to your paragraph.
const paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll(".rounded-container > p")
window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; ++i) {
        if (paragraphs[i].clientHeight > reference) paragraphs[i].classList.add("toggled")
        else if (paragraphs[i].clientHeight <= reference && paragraphs[i].parentElement.classList.contains("toggled")) paragraphs[i].parentElement.classList.remove("toggled")
    }
})
```

CSS:

```
.toggled.rounded-container[data-icon-name="account"]::before {
    top: calc(-50% + 30px);
}
```